# async.js : forEachOf is not calling the last callback

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, async.js

I have checked all the posts on the subject, and added a callback in the iterator. 
However, it seems it does not work.

```js
  async.forEachOf(scoreTree.nodes, function (node,key, callback){
          if(!node.composition.weights){
            mongooseCall.etc.find({}
            }
            ,function (err, data) {
              //some synchronous code
              //use data to update node... 
              callback(null);
            });
          }
       },function (err) {
         lastCall(err, scoreTree, function () {scoreTree.save();});
       });
```

Thank you for your help!
Marouane.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The developer console is your friend and will show you likely errors with your code- looks like you have 1 too many `{` - just after your `mongooseCall.etc.find({}`

Try it like this:

```
async.forEachOf(scoreTree.nodes, function (node,key, callback){
          if(!node.composition.weights){
            mongooseCall.etc.find({}
            // } <- This is the one too many
            ,function (err, data) {
              //some synchronous code
              //use data to update node... 
              callback(null);
            });
          }
       },function (err) {
         lastCall(err, scoreTree, function () {scoreTree.save();});
       });
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I removed some code in the call to mongodb, I forgot one }. 
The main issue here is that "callback" is not called for all the nodes. 
Adding the else, fixes the issue.

```js
async.forEachOf(scoreTree.nodes, function (node,key, callback){
          if(!node.composition.weights){
            mongooseCall.etc.find({}
            // } <- This is the one too many 
            ,function (err, data) {
              //some synchronous code
              //use data to update node... 
              callback(null); //not called in all the cases
            });
          }else{
              //this needs to be added
              callback(null);
          }
       },function (err) {
         lastCall(err, scoreTree, function () {scoreTree.save();});
       });
```

Comment: Please delete this post. This is essentially a copy of my answer.

Comment: I added this : 
else{
              //this needs to be added
              callback(null);
          }Which was not before..

Comment: Doesn't matter - it wasn't needed to answer your initial question.